# How To Get LineHeight/FontHeight In MultiLine TextBox Using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, fonts

I have some text boxes having multiple line feature on with having different font size. Now I want to know the line height of this textbox text as its a simple text box so each line height will be same for a whole textbox as its not a RichTextBox.

[image]

So can we get it in a variable via C# programming? You can see the screenshot for more info.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks for your helpful reply @CodyGray and finally I got my desired answer by just little editing of your code as below and its working perfectly.

```
int lineHeight;
using (Graphics g = textBox1.CreateGraphics())
{
    lineHeight = Convert.ToInt32(g.MeasureString("A", textBox1.Font).Height);
}
```

Comment: As mentioned at the bottom of my answer, this is the wrong solution: "There is also a `Graphics.MeasureString` method that does something very similar. But don't use it. It measures the string as if it were to be drawn by GDI+, but the built-in controls all use GDI to draw their text, so you need `TextRenderer.MeasureText`."

Answer (score 5):

To measure text, use [`TextRender.MeasureText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext.aspx).

If you are not interested in the width, you can call the function in a very simple way:

```
int textHeight;
using (Graphics g = textBox1.CreateGraphics())
{
    textHeight = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font).Height;
}
```

As you said, if every line uses the same font (as it would for a TextBox), then every line will have the same height, so you can just multiply the height by the number of lines.

But you can also use `TextRenderer.MeasureText` to determine both the width and height required to display the text. For example:

```
Size szText;
using (Graphics g = textBox1.CreateGraphics())
{
    szText = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g,
                                      textBox1.Text,
                                      textBox1.Font,
                                      textBox1.ClientSize,
                                      TextFormatFlags.Left
                                        | TextFormatFlags.Top
                                        | TextFormatFlags.NoPrefix
                                        | TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl);
}
```

<sub>(There is also a `Graphics.MeasureString` method that does something very similar. But don't use it. It measures the string as if it were to be drawn by GDI+, but the built-in controls all use GDI to draw their text, so you need `TextRenderer.MeasureText`.)</sub>

Comment: I have a little problem with your solution now. You answer is working fine but its giving me total height of the text from the top border of `textBox1` mean I have have 4 line of text then its giving me the height from top border of `textBox1` to 4th line of text But what my question is to know the **LineHeight/FontHeight** only not the full text height. So what to update now in the code...???

Comment: I tried to use this code but its also not giving perfect result......

`int pixels;
using (Graphics g = textBox1.CreateGraphics())
{
float points = textBox1.Font.SizeInPoints;
pixels = Convert.ToInt16(points * g.DpiX / 72);                    
}
MessageBox.Show("myFont size in pixels: " + pixels);`

Comment: I also tried to do this by using but its also not giving perfect result...... `int fontHeight = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Font.Size);`